# Crop the object from infrared picture. Rstudio/Python

Tags: python, rstudio

I am trying to crop only liver from this picture. I have tried everything but cannot find any useful information about it. I am using Python/Rstudio. Also after removing the unnecessary part, I am willing to get pixels/intensity of the new image. Any help would be appreciated. [Please check one of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhqQC.png) [This is somehow what I want to crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMyp9.png)

UPDATE:

I am trying to crop the main image based on edges I got from the canny edge detector. Is there any way to crop the main image based on edges? Please check the images. 
[Liver Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0y7e.jpg)
[Canny Edge Detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRDUJ.jpg)

Comment: Pls include the code you tried

Comment: are your all images of the same size? and are they taken from the same angle, i.e. the liver is shown not upside down or with some other transformation?

Comment: @eugen yes, all the images are same size and they are taken from the same angle.

Comment: have you looked at my answer below?

Comment: @eugen hey, sorry for late reply. Unfortunately It didn't work. For some reason while I cropped that image, it changed all the values to 255. But in actual image, they are not same. I am trying to crop that image with edge detector. In which, I have edges of the liver and original picture. Is there any way to crop that picture based on the edges obtained in canny edge detection?  Also, please check the main post for the images I got. Thanks!

Comment: @AdityaPatel your update is actually a change from the original post. I think you should open a new post/question and if my question answered your original question, accept it or not

Comment: @eugen sure, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your images are static, same size, and taken from the same angle, then below simple script should suffice your needs:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("cMyp9.png")
mask = np.where(img==255)
img2 = cv2.imread("your_next_image.png")
img2 [mask] = 255
```

now your img2 is a cropped version